# Quicksort parallel arrays with respect to both arrays at the same time

Tags: c, arrays, quicksort

I have two parallel arrays, a double a[] and an int b[], that I am trying to sort using quicksort. 
I want to sort the first array a[] in descending order and at the same time swap the values of b[]. 
Simultaneously, for elements of a[] with the same value, the elements of b[] must be sorted in ascending order. 
I have adjusted the following code, but I can't figure out how to achieve the last part.

```
void qsort1(double a[], int b[], int lo, int hi) {
 int h, l, p, t1;
 double t;

 if (lo < hi) {
   l = lo;
   h = hi;
   p = a[hi];

   do {
     while ((l < h) && (a[l] <= p)) 
        l = l+1;
     while ((h > l) && (a[h] >= p))
        h = h-1;
     if (l < h) {
        t = a[l];
        a[l] = a[h];
        a[h] = t;
        t1 = b[l];
        b[l] = b[h];
        b[h] = t1;
      }
   } while (l < h);

   a[hi] = a[l];
   a[l] = p;

   qsort1( a, b, lo, l-1 );
   qsort1( a, b, l+1, hi );
 }
}
```

For example:

Arrays at the beginning:

a[1] = 10   b[1] = 1 
a[2] = 15   b[2] = 2 
a[3] = 20   b[3] = 3 
a[4] = 15   b[4] = 4

Arrays in the end:

a[1] = 20   b[1] = 3 
a[2] = 15   b[2] = 2 
a[3] = 15   b[3] = 4 
a[4] = 10   b[4] = 1

Comment: The "array" `a` is an array of `double`, yet the temporary variable `t` which you use for the swap is an `int`. That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: And can you please elaborate what you mean on your problem? What "last part" is causing you trouble? For the example input you show, what is the *actual* output? And have you tried to step through the code line by line in a debugger to make sure it works as intended?

Comment: This maybe OT but... why not put a double and an integer into a struct and then have a single array of that struct. This will allow you to use standard qsort on that array. As a benefit it will be easy to write the compare function to sort on the integer value in case the double value is the same.

Comment: The part that is causing me trouble, is to sort b[] in ascending order for the lines that the elements of a[] have the same value. F.e., if a[5]=a[6]=a[7] and b[5]=20, b[6]=16, b[7]=8, I want to sort b[] in ascending order, and it will be b[5]=8, b[6]=16, b[7]=20.

Comment: I tested the ascending order of a[i] and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @4386427 I don't know how to use structures, so I tried with parallel arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid two independent arrays. Instead I would make a struct that contained one double and one integer and make an array of that struct. The benefit is two things:

1) The array can be sorted by standar qsort

2) The requirement about sorting on the double first and sort on the integer in case of equal double values, can easily be implemented by the compare function.

It can look something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  double a;
  int b;
} SomeDataType;

int compar(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  SomeDataType* pa = (SomeDataType*)a;
  SomeDataType* pb = (SomeDataType*)b;
  if (pa->a > pb->a) return -1;
  if (pa->a < pb->a) return 1;
  if (pa->b > pb->b) return 1;
  if (pa->b < pb->b) return -1;
  return 0;
}

void pd(SomeDataType* p, int n)
{
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
  {
    printf("%f - %d\n", p[i].a, p[i].b);
  }
}
int main()
{
  SomeDataType arr[] = {{10.0, 1}, {15.0, 2}, {20.0, 3}, {15.0, 4}};
  pd(arr, 4);
  qsort(arr, 4, sizeof(SomeDataType), compar);
  printf("-------------------------\n");
  pd(arr, 4);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10.000000 - 1
15.000000 - 2
20.000000 - 3
15.000000 - 4
-------------------------
20.000000 - 3
15.000000 - 2
15.000000 - 4
10.000000 - 1
```

If it's important to have two individual arrays in the program, I would still use `qsort` and an array of structs. I would do the sorting in 3 steps.

1) Copy data from the individual arrays to an array of structs

2) Sort the array of structs using `qsort`

3) Copy the sorted data in the array of structs back to the individual arrays

That could look like:

```
typedef struct
{
  double a;
  int b;
} SomeDataType;

int compar(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  SomeDataType* pa = (SomeDataType*)a;
  SomeDataType* pb = (SomeDataType*)b;
  if (pa->a > pb->a) return -1;
  if (pa->a < pb->a) return 1;
  if (pa->b > pb->b) return 1;
  if (pa->b < pb->b) return -1;
  return 0;
}

void qsort1(double a[], int b[], int lo, int hi)
{
 if (lo < hi)
 {
   int num_elements = hi - lo + 1;
   SomeDataType* p = malloc(num_elements * sizeof *p);

   // Copy from individual arrays to array of structs
   for(int i=0; i<num_elements; ++i)
   {
     p[i].a = a[lo+i];
     p[i].b = b[lo+i];
   }

   // Sort array of structs
   qsort(p, num_elements, sizeof *p, compar);

   // Copy from array of structs  back to individual arrays
   for(int i=0; i<num_elements; ++i)
   {
     a[lo+i] = p[i].a;
     b[lo+i] = p[i].b;
   }

   free(p);
 }
}

void pa(double a[], int b[], int n)
{
   for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
   {
     printf("a[%d] = %f b[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i], i, b[i]);
   }
}

int main()
{
  double a[] = {10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0};
  int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  pa(a, b, 4);
  qsort1(a, b, 0, 3);
  printf("-------------------------\n");
  pa(a, b, 4);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a[0] = 10.000000 b[0] = 1
a[1] = 15.000000 b[1] = 2
a[2] = 20.000000 b[2] = 3
a[3] = 15.000000 b[3] = 4
-------------------------
a[0] = 20.000000 b[0] = 3
a[1] = 15.000000 b[1] = 2
a[2] = 15.000000 b[2] = 4
a[3] = 10.000000 b[3] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code. How can I implement two arrays of different type in the `SomeDataType arr[] = {{10.0, 1}, {15.0, 2}, {20.0, 3}, {15.0, 4}};` part? My arrays are double and int, so I don't think this can happen.

Comment: @GiannisD There are two types (i.e. a double and an integer) in the struct so you only need one array

Comment: @GiannisD See updated answer where the second example uses two individual arrays